# A clever script for logging program run

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

**Situation:**

The system is used to run high end calculations taking long time. Glad to use Ubuntu for this system. The process is started with a script which calls the program(s). This script can have different names.

I keep moving from place to place, and I cannot keep a written log of scripts running presently or stopped/failed or finished successfully. Hence, I use the original script to make an entry in a file. Following is the current version of my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Running QM-JOB: helix HPC

    echo -e 'Job started @ '$dt'' >> /home/helix/calc/runlog.log

    #cd ~/ChemPackage/dalton/dalton  #32bit calc installation
    cd /home/vayu/ChemPackage/dalton_mod/dalton # custom coded (ln 56,548,954)modified installation
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
    df -h /dev/md0
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
    export DALTON_TMPDIR=/mnt/raid0/scratch
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=24
    source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
    source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64

    echo "//-------process started-GEOMETRY-OPTIMIZATION------//"
    dt1=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');

    #following line calls the program and runs the job.
    ./dalton -b ~/dalton/ExtBasis -w  ~/dalton/calc/opt -omp 24 -mb 24000 geom_opt_preopt_l2 molecule

    dt2=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');

    echo "//-----------------process FINISHED ----------------//"
```

I presently log the job run using the following line,

`echo -e 'Job started @ '$dt'' >> /home/helix/calc/runlog.log`

**Now I want to make this script more intelligent. My plan:**

1. Use regex idea to log the *program name* and *file names* tab separated in a single line. The line calling the program and the files is following,

`./dalton -b ~/dalton/ExtBasis -w  ~/dalton/calc/opt -omp 24 -mb 24000 <file_1> <file_2>`

The position of file names for this program is fixed. For other programs I can modify once I get an idea how to do that.

2. Log the time duration of the job. By using the start and end time; `dt1` and `dt2`. It would be better to use dynamic units ( say `minutes` if process finished within an hour, and `hours` if finished before a day, and then `days` if taking more than a day.
3. Log whether the process finished successfully by using `tail -20 <file1>_<file_2>.out`  The output is given as a file which has file name as concatenation of first file name and second file name with an underscore `_` in between with extension `.out`.

Can someone help me improve my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my script as following: 
Following script can be modified to work with other calculation packages ( here is use dalton).

**Using**
`./<script name> <file1> <file2>` (File1 and File2 are specific to the program I am using.)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Running QM-JOB: helix HPC
        d="$1"  # .dal file
        m="$2"  # .mol file
    dt=$(date  '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
    echo -e 'Job started @ '$dt'' >> ~/dalton/runlog.log
    cd /home/vayu/ChemPackage/dalton_mod/dalton # custom coded (ln 56,548,954)modified installation
    echo "-----------Scratch Disk Info-------------------"
    df -h /dev/md0
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
    export DALTON_TMPDIR=/mnt/raid0/scratch
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6
    source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
    source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64

    echo "//---------------process started-------------------//"
    dt1=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
    #following line calls the program and runs the job.
    ./dalton -b ~/dalton/ExtBasis -w  ~/dalton/calc/molecule -omp 6 -mb 15999 $d $m

    dt2=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
    dateutils.ddiff "$dt1" "$dt2" #time duration of job

    echo "//-----------------process FINISHED ----------------//"
    output=$( "$d"_"$m"".out")      ; echo $output
    tail -10 "$output" #last 10 lines of output file which tell me about the job's completion status(successful or failed !).
    echo "//--------------------------------------------------//"
```